# Isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}[i]/{p}$ and $\mathbb{F}^2_p$

Tags: number-theory, quotient-spaces

Say $p$ is a prime number such that $p=4k+1$. I need to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/p$ (quotient ring) and $\mathbb{F}^2_{p}$ are isomorphic. I know that since $p \equiv 1 \mod4$ I can say that $p=xy$ where $x,y$ are conjugate prime numbers in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, so I tried using the CRT (Chinese remainder theorem) - so I know that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/p$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[i]/x\times\mathbb{Z}[i]/y$, but I wasn't able to take it from there. Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: The hint is to prove $\Bbb Z[i]/(x)\cong\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: as a further hint, recall that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID, so prime ideals in it are maximal

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom What is exactly the definition of $\mathbb{Z}[i]/{(x)}$? When we talk about $\mathbb{Z}\(x)$ the meaning is obvious, but it's not so obvious in this notation.

Comment: So, $(x)$ is shorthand for the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ generated by $x$; this is also denoted $\mathbb{Z}[i]x$, and it consists of the set of elements $(a+bi)x$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. You can verify that this is an ideal, and hence it makes sense to quotient by it, and $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(x)$ is then just the ring consisting of all cosets $a+bi+(x)$. (I assume you've come across the definition of a general quotient rings?)

Comment: I'm still not sure how to take it from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More precisely we have
$$\mathbb{Z}[i]/(p) \cong \mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X^2+1) \cong
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{F}_{p^2} &\text{if } p \equiv 3 \pmod 4\\
\mathbb{F}_{p} \times \mathbb{F}_{p} &\text{if } p \equiv 1 \pmod 4
\end{cases}$$

So the comment on whether it is written $\Bbb F_{p^2}$ or $\Bbb F_p^2$ was really meaningful.

Reference: [Quotient ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a+bi)$ when $a$ and $b$ are NOT coprime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868345/quotient-ring-of-gaussian-integers-mathbbzi-abi-when-a-and-b-are-n)